# How can I create a numpy array with multiple fields per index?

Tags: python, numpy

Example:

```
array[0] = [item1,item2]
array[1] = [item1,item2]
array[2] = [item1,item2]
array[3] = [item1,item2]
```

How to create a array like this in python?

Comment: Are the items all going to be the same type? If all your `item1`s and `item2`s are going to be of the same type, you just want a 2D array.

Comment: Also, are you actually using numpy? It's not clear from your original question whether you're actually using numpy arrays, or whether the tag is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways which look similar but are actually quite different:

The first way is to create a two dimensional array:

```
import numpy as np

foo = np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]])
# foo = np.arange(4*2).reshape(4,2)   # this does the same thing
print(foo[0])    # the first row of `foo`
# [0 1]

print(foo[1])    # the second row of `foo`
# [2 3]
```

The second way is to create a one-dimensional array of dtype `'object'`, where the objects are Python lists:

```
bar = np.empty(4, dtype='object')
bar[0] = [0,1]
bar[1] = [2,3]
bar[2] = [4,5]
bar[3] = [6,7]

print(bar[0])
# [0, 1]

print(bar[1])
# [2, 3]
```

Note that in the first example, `foo[0]` is a NumPy array. In the second example, `bar[0]` is a Python list.

Numerical calculations done on `foo` will tend to be much quicker than similar operations done on `bar`. If the items stored in the Python lists are numeric and/or of a homogenous type (such as all strings), using a higher-dimensional NumPy array tends to be better choice than a NumPy array of dtype `object`. (Especially for numeric data, not only are there speed benefits to using homogenous arrays of non-object dtypes, but moreover, some NumPy functions do not work on arrays of `object` dtype.)

Answer (score 0):

What type are 'item1' and 'item2'? Also are they the same type? See the example below.

```
your_array = [[5,3], [3,6], [4, 9]] # you could do this
print(your_array[0]) # would print [5,3]
```